# If command running when its trigger isn't met

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Ok I have a batch program to help me with some of the side work I do, and I tend to update the code based on new features I want and to make it work better.

However this one "if not exist" command is running even though the user i test with is real

```
cls
set /p "user1=Select user to invoke action on: "

if not exist %user1% (
    echo User does not exist
    pause
    goto Main
)
set /p "admin=Enter "Add" to give admin, Enter "Delete" to remove admin: " 
net localgroup Administrators %user1% /%admin% pause
```

I've tried using else commands, and using multiple if commands, but this one "not exist" if command just runs weather the account is real or not

Comment: `%user1%` is referring to a file, right? `if exist` only checks for the existence of files.

Comment: Try making the comparison this way `"%user1%"=="main"`.

Comment: @SomethingDark `%user1%` refers to the actual account of a user so I can edit certain traits or permissions of said user. This specific set of code goes to changing administrator privileges of `%user1%`, heres more of the working code if it helps with a solution. `set /p "admin=Enter "Add" to give admin, Enter "Delete" to remove admin: "

 net localgroup Administrators %user1% /%admin%
 pause`

Comment: @dcg Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Read the help for the `IF` command.  There is an `/I` option for a case insensitive compare. Best practice for the `IF` command is to always surround your string comparisons in quotes and do not put any spaces between your strings and equals symbols.  Also you do not need the colon for the the label when using the `GOTO` command.  For your `IF NOT EXIST` command to work your working directory would need to be in the parent folder of all your user folders. For example: **C:\users** on newer versions of Windows.

Comment: @krakerjak9000, dcg's example is spot on based on the example you have provided. I find it hard to believe that it did not work. The example is a best practice for doing string comparisons in a batch-file.

Comment: @Squashman The part of the code that I changed with dcg's example still worked but it didn't solve the problem I have.

Comment: @krakerjak9000, You said your problem was the `IF` command not working. You just said dcg's example worked but didn't solve the problem.  That is a contradiction. Please update your question with further information otherwise your question will get closed as being unclear.

Comment: I've removed some code that's unrelated to my issue and reworded my explanation, so I hope this helps more and clears any confusion and contradiction. @Squashman

Comment: @krakerjak9000, what didn't you understand about SomethingDark's first comment and my first comment about the `IF EXIST` command.

Comment: `If` `%user1%` does `Not Exist` where? If your current directory is `C:\Users` then you should most likely use `If Not Exist "%user1%\"` or put in the full path, `If Not Exist "C:\Users\%user1%\"`. That said, this is not the correct way to determine if a user already exists on the system.

Comment: @Squashman, after I edited the question, I tried everything else that you and SomethingDark said, and am testing the new code.

Comment: It does work correctly now,  it was a directory issue. Thanks everyone that helped.

Comment: @krakerjak9000, I personally would not use the `IF EXIST` command to check if a user exists on the system.  You would be better off using the `NET USER` command.